# Does anyone know how to access the ringer and vibrate settings for WP7 in code?

Tags: windows-phone-7, settings, vibration

I'm doing a location aware app that will turn on and off the ringer and vibration according to location, I cannot find how to access these features in code.

Comment: Since Olivier has given you a useful answer, and you are unlikely to get a better answer, it may be appropriate to mark his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible with the current SDK.

Comment: Really! can I get a source for that? I'm doing it for a project. If I can get a citation it will get me off the hook for the lack of that feature.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsphone7series/thread/316E73F8-CCE1-46D5-B6E4-26BD31F6259C http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsphone7series/thread/ad44f24e-76f8-41db-a759-f80aa7e513a8 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/60e0c7f8-c3f0-4938-abd4-8c1c48a52a5a

Comment: Thanks Olivier, consider this one sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The ringtone isn't accessible directly as Olivier mentions. You could play the sounds directly of course, but this gets tricky when the user changes the ringtone.

Regarding Vibrate, you can access this here.

[VibrateController Class (Microsoft.Devices)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.vibratecontroller%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)